# Assigning launchOption to self in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

I'm trying to assign `launchOption` from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` to `self` so I can use it in another function but it doesn't seem to work.

I keep getting the error:

```
"Property 'launchOptions' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate *'" .
```

It seems like I'm having problems when I try to access `self.launchOptions`.

[image]

Comment: If you want your app delegate to have a `launchOptions` property you need to declare it.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks a lot, solved my problem! was very new to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppDelegate does not have a default implementation of `launchOptions`. In your AppDelegate class implementation you must create an instance variable and then you can assign to it. See below:

```
@implementation AppDelegate {
    NSDictionary launchOptions;

    -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *) application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
        self.launchOptions = launchOptions;
    }
}
```